# SAS data step vs. proc sql dates

Tags: sql, sas

I hope someone can help me answer this query: I have two programs, one in proc sql and one in data step. The proc sql works, the data step doesn't. I can't see why?

```
%let _run_date = '30-jun-2017';
proc sql;
        connect to oracle (path='EDRPRD' authdomain='EDRProduction' 
buffsize=32767);
        create table customer_sets as                              
        select * from connection to oracle (
        select *
        from    customer_set
        where   start_date <= &_run_date.
        and     nvl(end_date, &_run_date.) >= &_run_date.
        and     substr(sets_num,1,2) = 'R9');
quit;
```

This works fine. However, this doesn't:

```
libname ora oracle path='EDRPRD' authdomain='EDRProduction' schema='CST'; 
data customer_sets;
    set ora.customer_set;
    where   start_date le &_run_date. and
            coalesce(end_date, &_run_date.) ge &_run_date. and
            substr(sets_num,1,2) = "R9";
run;
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know Oracle SQL well enough to be sure, but two things stand out as needing investigation... your _run_date macro var is a character string, not a date literal, which would be '30jun2017'd; if the database column is actually a date column, SAS and Oracle may be handling the discrepancy in different ways. And the same thing for the COALESCE/NVL functions, which may behave slightly differently in some cases. I would break the queries down and check the values returned by the date comparisons and the functions.

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped to see the error log but, for starters, your date macro variable, as it is used in your data step is interpreted by SAS as a string literal, not a date. In SAS, date literals are enclosed in quotes (single or double) and followed by a `d`.
You can modify your data step as follows and see if that's any better:

```
%let _run_date = '30-jun-2017';
data customer_sets;
    set ora.customer_set;
    where   start_date le &_run_date.d and
            coalesce(end_date, &_run_date.d) ge &_run_date.d and
            substr(sets_num,1,2) = "R9";
run;
```

If that's not the issue, please post the log containing the error.

**EDIT**

Here is the above code with a small test data created beforehand:

```
libname ora (work);
data ora.customer_set;
infile datalines dlm='09'x;
input ID start_date :anydtdte. end_date :anydtdte. sets_num $;
format start_date end_date date.;
datalines;
1   30-may-2017 .   R9xxx
2   30-may-2017 31-may-2017 R9xxx
;
run;

%let _run_date = '30-jun-2017';
data customer_sets;
    set ora.customer_set;
    where   start_date le &_run_date.d and
            coalesce(end_date, &_run_date.d) ge &_run_date.d and
            substr(sets_num,1,2) = "R9";
run;
```

You can copy paste and run this as-is and you will see that it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes, I've tried every combination of SAS date, numeric and text before I asked this question! The error I get is:

`NOTE 138-205: Line generated by the macro variable "R_DATE".
35          '30-jun-2017'
            _
            22
             _
             200
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
              a missing value, (, +, -, :, INPUT, NOT, PUT, ^, ~.  

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.`

Comment: @RoryWilsher that log excerpt mentions a `R_DATE` macro variable yet the code you provided does not contain any such variable. This leads me to believe that this code did not generate that error message. Have you tried writing your code as I suggested with a `d` after the macro variable invocation? I ran it myself and it works fine (see edit in original answer)